# relation index and degree

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I'm having troubles to understand an equivalent definition, or characterization of the degree of mapping as an index of a vector field :

Consider $X \in C^\infty(\mathbb R^2, \mathbb R^2)$, $\, X(x)\neq 0, \, \forall x \in \mathbb S^1$. Define $F:\mathbb S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb S^1$ as $F(x) := \frac{X(x)}{||X(x)||}.$
Then $$\deg(F) = I_X(0),$$ where $I_X(x)$ is the *index* of the vector field $X$ at the point $x$, see definition below.

**How does this make sense?**

$\,$

> ***Definition.*** Let $\xi \in C(U,\mathbb R^2), \, U \subset \mathbb R^2 \, $open, a continuous vector field. Let all singularities (zeros) of $\xi$ be isolated. Let $x \in U$, $\,r > 0$ small enough, such that $$\{y \in \mathbb R^2 : 0 < |y - x| \leq r\} \subset U$$ and doesn't contain any singularities of $\xi$. Let $\varphi: [0,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a continuous polar function for the vector field $t \mapsto \xi(c(t))$ along the circle $c: t \mapsto x + r (\cos t, \sin t)$. Then $$ I(x) := I_\xi(x) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \big(\varphi (2\pi) - \varphi(0)\big), $$
>   and is independent of the coices made.

Any help is as always greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should start by fixing your definition of $F$.

Comment: ah yes! thank you, i updated it :-)